# Why appending box dimensions to a sequence (in a loop) makes that sequence only contain duplicates of last dimension?

Tags: boxes, expl3, latex3, dimensions

Loop steps from 1 through 9. Each step puts current index digit of the loop into a box and extracts the digit's width. The width is then appended as dimension value to a sequence. Although the sequence contains 9 values at the end, oddly all of them are dimension (width) of digit 9. All values of the sequence are overwritten to new dimension at each step. Maybe you can figure out the core of the problem.

```
\documentclass[varwidth=100mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Impact}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N\mySeq
\box_new:N\myBox
\int_step_inline:nn{9}
  { \hbox_set:Nn\myBox{#1}
    % display dimension before adding it to sequence
    #1=\dim_eval:n{\box_wd:N\myBox}\\ % output
    % add dimension to sequence
    \seq_put_right:Nn\mySeq
      {\dim_eval:n{\box_wd:N\myBox}}
    % display current contents of the sequence
    \seq_use:Nn\mySeq{_}\\\\
  }
% display all dimensions (contains only duplicates of last dimension)
\seq_use:Nn\mySeq{,~}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to expand the value: use

```
\seq_put_right:Nx
```

instead.

What's the problem? If you do

```latex
\hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { A }
\seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \dim_eval:n { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box } }
\hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { AA }
\seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \dim_eval:n { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box } }
```

this results in the sequence to contain the following items (without the outer braces, as it would be displayed by `\seq_show:N \l_tmpa_seq`)

```
{ \dim_eval:n { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box } }
{ \dim_eval:n { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box } }
```

When the sequence is used, the width of the current contents of `\l_tmpa_box` is employed: the value it had at the moment of assignment has *never* been mentioned.

With `\seq_put_right:Nx` you instead get the value *frozen* at the moment of the assignment.

Would it be “better” to use

```
\exp_args:NNx \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {...}
```

No. Using (or defining, in case of need) a variant is better style.

Comment: @bp2017 In my opinion it’s better to use variants, as in the present case

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yes, of course

Answer (score 6):

When you do:

```
\seq_put_right:Nn \mySeq { \dim_eval:n{ \box_wd:N \myBox } }
```

what you are appending to your sequence is the token list `\dim_eval:n{\box_wd:N\myBox}` (the tokens are `\dim_eval:n`, `{` with catcode 1, `\box_wd:N`, `\myBox` and `}` with catcode 2). The final `\dim_eval:n` is evaluated *too late,* once the loop has been fully executed and you do `\seq_use:Nn \mySeq {,~}`. At this point, `\myBox` contains the digit `9`, hence what you saw. As egreg [said](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/492677/73317) (faster than me), replace `\seq_put_right:Nn` with `\seq_put_right:Nx` to evaluate `\dim_eval:n` *inside* the loop, when `\myBox` still contains the relevant digit.

You have to realize that your sequence variable `\mySeq` does not contain any length at all: it contains **n times the same token list**, which I explicitated above, with n=0 at first, then n=1, ..., and finally n=9. In other words, it contains **n times the same “formula,”** stored in the form of a token list. This formula is comparable to a function of one variable, the box variable `\myBox`. Whenever you use `\seq_use:Nn \mySeq {...}`, you put n copies of the same formula in the input stream (where n is the current length of `\mySeq`), and when TeX expands one of the `\dim_eval:n` tokens and processes all tokens resulting from this expansion, this yields a length (precisely: a 〈dimen〉) according to the formula and the contents of `\myBox` at that point.

At the end of your example, your code therefore computes n=9 times the **same formula with the same value** of `\myBox`, an `\hbox` containing the figure `9`. In very explicit terms, your final `\seq_use:Nn` call is equivalent to this:

```latex
\dim_eval:n { \box_wd:N \myBox } ,~
\dim_eval:n { \box_wd:N \myBox } ,~
\dim_eval:n { \box_wd:N \myBox } ,~
\dim_eval:n { \box_wd:N \myBox } ,~
\dim_eval:n { \box_wd:N \myBox } ,~
\dim_eval:n { \box_wd:N \myBox } ,~
\dim_eval:n { \box_wd:N \myBox } ,~
\dim_eval:n { \box_wd:N \myBox } ,~
\dim_eval:n { \box_wd:N \myBox }
```

Calculating 9 times f(x) with the same function f and the same value of x gives 9 times the same result, hence the output you obtained.

For the `\seq_use:Nn` calls inside the loop, this is exactly the same, except that n is replaced by a number between 1 and 8, inclusive.

Note: as people already told you, your variables don't respect the LaTeX3 coding guidelines. Read [expl3.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/expl3.pdf) and [l3styleguide.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/l3styleguide.pdf) from [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel) (the beginning of [interface3.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) is also pretty useful to read at first, but I suppose you've already seen it).

Comment: I got tired to tell the OP about following the guidelines

Comment: @egreg Let's hope that with time comes wisdom. :-)

Comment: I added very detailed explanations to my answer. They tell you quite precisely when each of the 10 `\dim_eval:n` is evaluated. Please reread it now. Concerning the coding conventions, **they are here to help you;** rest assured that I absolutely don't care if you don't want to follow them. You'll be the one to lose in the end, because 1) your code will conflict with other people's code (precisely: people who don't want to respect the conventions) and 2) you'll be confusing local and global variables/assignments. But feel free to do as you want: I have nothing to gain trying to convince you.

Comment: I didn't say the loop ran with n=0. But **right after you created the `\mySeq` sequence variable,** it has precisely n=0 copies of the token list I explicitated in my answer. Then, as the loop goes, it has 1 copy of the token list, then 2 copies, ..., and finally 9. The sentence containing “n=0” describes the whole “life” of the `\mySeq` variable. You have to read *precisely what I wrote* and not make up things from my words.

Comment: 1) For code in a file that is never going to be a package, using `\l_my_` and `\g_my_` prefixes is probably acceptable, but the day you want to reuse such code with another one developed in the same way, you're trapped and have to rename everything. 2) The distinction between local and global assignments on the one hand, and local and global variables on the other hand, is very important. The naming convention helps a lot avoid errors. 3) If you want to understand well expansion, read the TeXbook (study each exercise!). LaTeX3 will become much clearer after that.