# How to adjust default horizontal and vertical space such that it meets following requirements (related to \parshape, custom list and picture spacing)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, lists, paragraphs, line-spacing

The requirements:

1. Height of pages in the document should not be constrained by constant length (although page width should be).
2. Every line in a paragraph should be indented more than the previous line of that paragraph (by constant length), with first line of each paragraph having no indent at all (indent of each successive line is incremented by constant length).

`OUTPUT APPROXIMATION:
            1         2         3
   123456789012345678901234567890 <<< PARAGRAPH WIDTH
   This is sentence 1. This is
     sentence 2. This is sentence
       3. This is sentence 4.\par
   This is sentence 1. This is
     sentence 2. This is sentence
       3. This is sentence 4.`

3. Picture placed inside of such paragraph below any line of the paragraph should be indented as if it (the picture) were the next line. However, a picture following another picture in the paragraph should be indented exactly as that picture (which it follows). First line that follows a picture in the paragraph should have same indent as that picture.

`OUTPUT APPROXIMATION:
            1         2         3
   123456789012345678901234567890 <<< PARAGRAPH WIDTH
   This is sentence 1. This is
     sentence 2. This is sentence
       3. This is sentence 4.
         | O O |
         |\ ^ /| <<< PICTURE (INDENTED AS A LINE OF PARAGRAPH)
         | --- |
          _____
         /O ^ O\
         | --- | <<< PICTURE (SAME INDENT AS PREVIOUS PICTURE)
         \_____/
         This is sentence 5. This
           is sentence 6.`

4. Lists placed inside of paragraphs described above should have their items themselves behave like those paragraphs with exception that the first line of an item instead of starting at no indent (like first line of a paragraph does) should start at greater indent than the line preceding the item (unless that line belongs to another item of same list, in which case both items are indented the same).

`OUTPUT APPROXIMATION:
            1         2         3
   123456789012345678901234567890 <<< PARAGRAPH WIDTH
   This is sentence 1. This is
     sentence 2. This is sentence
       3. This is sentence 4:
         1. This is item 1. This <<< LIST LABEL IS INDENTED AS
              is still item 1.         A LINE OF PARAGRAPH
                Item 1 again.        POST-LABEL LINE-INDENTS BEHAVE
         2. This is item 2. This       AS USUAL BUT WITH
         |    is still item 2:           LABEL WIDTH ADDED TO EACH
         |      a) This is item <<< SUB-ITEM AFTER ITEM LINE BEHAVES
         |           "a". Still       AS IF IT WERE ITEM AFTER
         |             item "a".        PARAGRAPH LINE
         |      b) This is item
         |          "b".
         This is sentence 5. This
           is sentence 6.`

5. Optional borders should be available around each paragraph, list item, or picture (allowing for paragraphs, list items, and pictures to be separated by horizontal lines, as well as allowing for equations contained within pictures to start with a wide vertical line).
6. Vertical spacing between paragraphs, between paragraphs and pictures, or between pictures should be equal to interline spacing of a paragraph (should be constant throughout the document, with one exception below).
7. If one paragraph or picture (solely containing equation or text) is completely (or almost completely) comprised of larger or smaller font size than the previous paragraph or picture, then vertical spacing between them should be split: such that one half of vertical spacing depends on font size of upper paragraph or picture and is contained within it (within frame of that paragraph or picture) while another half of vertical spacing (likewise) depends on font size of lower paragraph or picture and is (likewise) contained within it (each half of such mixed vertical spacing should be contained within its respective paragraph or picture, such that vertical space of larger font remains within confines of a structure where the text of that font is and likewise for smaller font).

`OUTPUT APPROXIMATION:
   large font size (20pt) <<< PARAGRAPH 1
     | <<< LARGE FONT-SIZE INTERLINE-SPACING
   ---------------------- <<< END OF PARAGRAPH-1 FRAME
   ---------------------- <<< START OF PARAGRAPH-2 FRAME
     | <<< NORMAL FONT-SIZE INTERLINE-SPACING
   normal font size (10pt) <<< PARAGRAPH 2`

---

Let's start with a code sample. It has several problems: (1) it's hard to position the border of math-equation node immediately after the border of preceding paragraph-line (or position it interline-space distance away from that line), (2) border of math-equation node overlaps with right-side bound of the page if 25mm (paragraph last-line's remaining length available after indent of 15mm) is specified (so I have no idea what to add to or subtract from 25mm to make the border of the math-equation node touch without overlap the border of the page), (3) border of math-equation node overlaps with bottom-side bound of the page too.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path node[inner sep=0,draw,text width=40mm,anchor=north west]
      { \parbox{\hsize}
          { \parshape 4 0mm 40mm 5mm 35mm 10mm 30mm 15mm 25mm
            \fboxrule0.1pt
            \fboxsep0pt
            \fbox{hello world}\newline
            \fbox{hello world}\newline
            \fbox{hello world}\newline
            % FOLLOWING DIM EXPRESSION IS NOT ENOUGH TO ALIGN THE NODE FRAME EXACTLY BELOW THE \fbox OF THE PARAGRAPH-LINE (NODE FRAME IS SLIGHTLY HIGHER THAN THE \fbox FRAME)
            \vspace{\dimexpr-\lineskip-\baselineskip+0.1pt}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            % 25mm (WIDTH OF LAST LINE, CONSIDERING INDENT OF 15mm) IS TOO WIDE, SO THE NODE FRAME OVERLAPS WITH THE PAGE FRAME; 24mm IS NOT APPROPRIATE WIDTH TO ALIGN THE NODE FRAME AT DOCUMENT BOUND WITHOUT WITHOUT OVERLAP
              \path node[draw,text width=24mm]
                { \parbox{\hsize}
                    { \begin{gather*}
                        2+2=4
                      \end{gather*}
                    }
                };
            \end{tikzpicture}
          }
      };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

You can use your own approach and completely modify this code sample so that it's unrecognizable from the original. What I care about is making the conditions described above work.

---

PROGRESS:

UPDATE: [this answer (by egreg)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/495186/141768) solved how to position math-equation node-frame right below the frame of the `\fbox` by reducing `\newline\vspace{\dimexpr-\lineskip-\baselineskip+0.1pt}` to `\vspace{-\lineskip}\newline`. But generating vertical space between those frames equal to interline-spacing is still unsolved problem. I guess we can use `1ex` or something font-size dependent to generate vertical space where we don't have interline-space length available. Let's make it 1ex then: `\vspace{\dimexpr-\lineskip+1ex}\newline`.

UPDATE: (David Carlisle suggested that) aside from using `standalone` class with `tikz` option to crop height of pages, `\pdfpageheight` can be used.

UPDATE: It's been suggested (by marmot) not to nest `tikz` pictures directly but to save them in boxes instead (to avoid confusing `tikz` and, therefore, avoid unexpected behavior; `tikz` doesn't expect picture environments to be directly nested inside other picture environments, that's my take from the links provided).

UPDATE: Great progress on alignment of node frames has been made. It turns out, when you set `inner sep` to zero, the `text width` starts at the middle of frame's left side and extends to the middle of frame's right side. Similarly with text height: text starts at the middle of frame's top side and extends to the middle of frame's bottom side. This creates complexity by requiring inner node's `text width` to "know" outer node's `line width`, which can be avoided. (See [this answer, by marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/495180/141768).)

Comment: It again nests `tikzpicture`s. There won't be a reliable solution as long as you keep doing this. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47377/121799 and the posts linking to it in order to understand that nesting `tikzpicture`s is really bad.

Comment: I never so an example in which nesting `tikzpicture`s is necessary. All you inner `tikzpicture` seems to do is to draw a node. This you can do in the outer `tikzpicture`. If you want to remove the gaps, set `outer sep=0pt`.

Comment: "I need to use standalone class, because not all pages (if any) are of the same size in my document. " why does that force standalone? what way do page sizes change? different length?, different width?

Comment: you seem to be anyway fixing the width to get line breaking, so not using most of the features of standalone

Comment: lots of examples on site of doing that sort of thing, mostly with article class https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299005/automatic-page-size-to-fit-arbitrary-content/299008#299008

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35847/varying-page-lengths

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408250/variable-page-length-1-page-per-section-with-luatex

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27041/automate-fixed-width-page-length-some-minimum-length-but-only-as-long-as-nee

Answer (score 3):

My advice would be to start with the basic requirements and implement those first, add fancier things such as boxing as you go on. Similarly specifying the PDF page height based on the document content is covered by several existing answers on site as noted in comments under the question.

This might be a start just implementing the basic indent and list layout as far as I understood it.

Note that as no extra box layers are introduced, there are no issues with `\lineskip` spacing, TeX's standard line breaking ensures even line spacing throughout.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength\textheight{2\textheight}
\pdfpageheight2\paperheight
\newdimen\zzindent
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\makeatletter

\setlength\zzindent{5mm}
\def\setpshape#1{\zpshape{0}{#1}{\the\dimexpr\linewidth-#1\relax}{}}
\def\zpshape#1#2#3#4{%
\ifdim#2<\linewidth
\edef\zztmp{%
\noexpand\zpshape
{\the\numexpr#1+1\relax}%
{\the\dimexpr#2+\zzindent}%
{\the\dimexpr#3-\zzindent}%
{#4 #2 #3}}\zztmp
\else
\xdef\zcurrentshape{#1 #4 }%
\parshape#1 #4 %
\fi}

\def\enumerate{%
\ifhmode
\par
\endgroup
\let\endenumerate\hendenumerate
\everypar\expandafter{\expandafter\setpshape\expandafter{\the\dimexpr\prevgraf\zzindent\relax}}%
\else
\let\endenumerate\vendenumerate
\fi
\def\item{\par\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi. }%
}

\def\hendenumerate{\par
\def\par{\endgraf\everypar{\setpshape{0pt}}\let\par\endgraf}%
\ignorespacesafterend\begingroup\def\@currenvir{enumerate}}

\def\vendenumerate{\par}




\begin{document}

\everypar{\setpshape{0pt}}

one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five 
one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five 
one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five 
one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five 
one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five
one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five 
one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five 
one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five 
one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five 


one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five 
one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five 
one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five 
one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five 
one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five
one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five 
one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five 
one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five 
one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five 



one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five 
one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five 
one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five 
one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five 
one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five
\begin{enumerate}% in para list
\item aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa
  bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc 
  bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc 
  bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc 
\item aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa
  bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc 
  bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc 
  bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc 
  bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc 
  bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc 
\end{enumerate}
% text after in para list
one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five 
one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five 
one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five 
one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five 


zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz
zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz
zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz

\begin{enumerate}% par list starts in vmode
\item aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa
  bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc 
  bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc 
  bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc 
\item aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa
  bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc 
  bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc 
  bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc 
  bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc 
  bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb ccc 
\end{enumerate}
% text after  par list
one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five 
one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five 
one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five 
one two three four five one two three four five one two three four five 

\end{document}
```

Comment: @bp2017 what is the document that needs the weird layout (do not feel you have to answer, but I felt I had to ask:-)

Comment: @bp2017 actually the first two lines are indented by the 5mm increment but I included the item number in the line, so with single digits it gives that appearance, it is easy to set the item number separately and so adjust the parshape logic if that's what you need.

Comment: @bp2017 you could use expl3 or simply use `\makebox[1cm]{\theenumi}` or whatever fixed width you want to force a fixed label width, and then adjust the first entry in the parshape to match, it's really a minor detail.

Comment: @bp2017 you asked that before... https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/492672/why-appending-box-dimensions-to-a-sequence-in-a-loop-makes-that-sequence-only

Comment: @bp2017 exactly same issue as in the question I linked to, there you asked why you got multiple values of a variable at the end of a loop, here I'm looping building up `\parshape` so I need to evaluate the value at each stage. compare `\edef\z{\dimen0} \edef\z{\z \dimen0} \show\z` with `\edef\z{\the\dimen0} \edef\z{\z \the\dimen0} \show\z`

Answer (score 1):

How about avoiding to nest `tikzpicture`s?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength\innerPicLineWidth
\setlength\innerPicLineWidth{0.8pt}
\newlength\outerPicLineWidth
\setlength\outerPicLineWidth{1.5pt}

% SAVE INNER PICTURE IN A BOX (INSTEAD OF NESTING DIRECTLY;
%  DIRECT NESTING HAS COMPLICATIONS)
\newsavebox\picbox
\sbox\picbox
  {% MAKE SURE NO SPACE IS PRESENT HERE (OTHERWISE FRAMES OVERLAP)
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \path node
        [ draw=red,
          %
          % IF inner sep IS HALF THE line width, NODE CONTENTS
          %  DON'T OVERLAP WITH THE FRAME AND NODE WIDTH IS
          %   (line width * 2 + text width), WHICH IS INTUITIVE
          %
          % IF inner sep IS ZERO, CONTENTS OF A NODE OVERLAP WITH
          %  ITS FRAME AND NODE WIDTH IS (line width + text width)
          %
          % THIS HAS IMPLICATIONS: IF OUTER AND INNER NODES BOTH
          %  HAVE inner sep SET TO ZERO, STRETCHING INNER NODE TO
          %   FILL OUTER NODE WITHOUT OVERLAPPING WITH OUTER
          %    NODE'S FRAME WOULD REQUIRE INNER NODE'S text width
          %     TO "KNOW" OUTER NODE'S line width (BUT THIS CAN BE
          %      AVOIDED BY SETTING inner sep OF EACH NODE TO HALF
          %       OF ITS line width)
          %
          inner sep=\innerPicLineWidth/2,
          line width=\innerPicLineWidth,
          text width=25mm-\innerPicLineWidth*2
        ]
        { \parbox{\hsize}
            { \begin{gather*}
                2+2=4
              \end{gather*}
            }
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path node
      [ draw=blue,
        inner sep=\outerPicLineWidth/2,
        line width=\outerPicLineWidth,
        text width=40mm
      ]
      { \parbox{\hsize}
          { \parshape 4 0mm 40mm 5mm 35mm 10mm 30mm 15mm 25mm
            \fboxrule0.1pt
            \fboxsep0pt
            \fbox{hello world}\newline
            \fbox{hello world}\newline
            \fbox{hello world}
            % GENERATE 1ex SPACE INSTEAD OF \lineskip SPACE
            %  BETWEEN INNER NODE FRAME AND \fbox FRAME
            \vspace{\dimexpr-\lineskip+1ex}\newline
            \usebox\picbox
          }
      };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: ENTIRE OUTER NODE]
[image: OUTER NODE'S TOP-LEFT CORNER]
[image: INNER NODE'S TOP-RIGHT CORNER]
[image: INNER NODE'S BOTTOM-LEFT CORNER]

Comment: @bp2017 Are you looking for `\path node[draw=red,text width=25mm-\pgflinewidth,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt]` for the first node that goes to the `\savebox`? Notice that there several dimensions in `tikzpicture`s, such as the inner and outer seps (which are really `inner xsep`, `inner ysep` and the same for outer). And of course the line has a width which is symmetric around the boundary path. And note that this is the reason why you should never nest `tikzpicture`s: the pgf keys of the outer will get applied to the inner one.

Comment: @bp2017 I do not know what the aim is but how about `text width=25mm-2*\pgflinewidth`?

Comment: @bp2017 Sounds like a fair compromise. ;-)

Comment: @bp2017 That is really up to you (but beware of a particular user who always claims making the codes of others "more concise" ;-)

Comment: @bp2017 Yes, my main problem is that I do not understand what the main goal of this exercise is. Once I understand it I will be happy to try to find a solution that neither nest `tikzpicture`s nor uses saveboxes but just works, but as long I do not understand the goal this will be hard.

Comment: @bp2017 I feel it is actually fine if you write a self-answer (as long as others benefit from it). I contributed very little.

Comment: @bp2017 Not at all.